# Overwatch Sombra ARG community asking for Cryto/Steg help

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptanalysis

We are looking for some crypto / security expertise in solving some difficult puzzles in a ARG campaign for a Blizzard game called Overwatch. The challenges introduced and solved by the community range from cryptographic / stenographic challenges but are well documented on the wiki page: http://wiki.gamedetectives.net/index.php?title=Sombra_ARG. At the current stage of this ARG several clues and riddles have been solved and at this current stage we are have a website advertising a slow transmission: http://amomentincrime.com/
What are asking for your help in solving the two unsolved challenges which can be found on this on the wiki page linked previously, here are the titles for the two challenges:
• Welcome to the Summer Games Video • Image of Reaper

Comment: It might be better if you approach with specific questions instead of asking for general help.